# Control the flow from SQS to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, fifo

I am working on a design to **control the flow of requests** to external Http endpoint from AWS SQS Queue. My existing design contains SQS FIFO Queue which is integrated into a lambda function, which makes a call to an external endpoint as soon the request receives from the queue. Http request to external Http API returns "success" status code as soon as it receives the request and returns the response later to the callback endpoint URL (provided as part of Http request payload) after processing the request. 
Now, the new business requirement is to not send another request to external API until the previous request is done with the processing (or done calling the callback endpoint). Can anyone help me in providing the solution for this requirement, as the current design does not wait for the result to come back, before sending another request to an external endpoint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: What is the problem or your question?

Comment: How long does the external system take to process the request? Seconds, Minutes, Hours? How many requests do you need to process per second/minute/hour? What will your system do once it is able to retrieve the result from the external API?

Comment: ranges between 1-3 minutes, but some request might go beyond that.

Comment: How many requests do you need to process per second/minute/hour? What will your system do once it is able to retrieve the result from the external API?

Comment: 10 requests at a time and once the request gets completed by external api, it should send another request to the target system.